# Prevent Gatsby page at a specific domain path from appearing in Google Search

Tags: javascript, reactjs, seo, gatsby

Is it possible to prevent a Gatsby page at a specific domain path from appearing in Google Search.

I don't want to prevent the whole site from appearing in Google Search, just one page that exists at a specific path. e.g. [www.mywebsite.co.uk/hide-me](http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/hide-me)

Answer (score 3):

Use the `<Helmet>` component to set the robot's `meta` tag.

```
const HideMe = ()=>{
  return <>
    <Helmet>
      <meta name={`robots`} content={`noindex, nofollow`} />
    </Helmet>;
    <h1>I'm the Hide Me page </h1>
  </>;
```

Most of the Gatsby starters comes with a `SEO` component which contains, among other stuff, the robots `meta` tag, if that's your case, you may need to customize it for each page passing the proper `prop`. For example:

```
const SEO = ({ index, follow, description, lang, meta, title }) => {
  const { site } = useStaticQuery(graphql`
              query getAllMetadata {
                  site {
                      siteMetadata {
                          title
                          description
                          author
                      }
                  }
              }
    `,
  );
  const metaDescription = description ?? site.siteMetadata.description;

  return <Helmet htmlAttributes={{ lang }} title={title} titleTemplate={`%s | ${site.siteMetadata.title}`}>
    <meta name={`robots`} content={`${index ? `index`:`noindex`},${follow ? `follow`:`nofollow`}`}/>
    <meta name={`description`} content={metaDescription}/>
    <meta name={`og:title`} content={title}/>
    <meta name={`og:description`} content={metaDescription}/>
    <meta name={`og:type`} content={`website`}/>
    <meta name={`twitter:card`} content={`summary`}/>
    <meta name={`twitter:creator`} content={site.siteMetadata.author}/>
    <meta name={`twitter:title`} content={title}/>
    <meta name={`twitter:description`} content={metaDescription}/>
  </Helmet>;
};
```

*Note: I'm assuming both `index` and `follow` as booleans but customize it as you wish or whatever fits you more*

If that's your case, in your `/hide-me` page you will have something like:

```
const HideMe = ()=>{
  return <>
    <SEO index={false} follow={false} />
    <h1>I'm the Hide Me page </h1>
  </>;
```

Moreover, you will need to add to all links that point to that page the `rel` attribute `nofollow` to avoid tracking by Google's crawlers.

```
<Link rel={`nofollow`} to={`/hide-me`}>Untracked link</Link>
```

In addition, you may also want to remove that page from the `sitemap.xml` (in case you have it) file, you can easily achieve it using one of the sitemap plugins like [`gatsby-plugin-sitemap`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-sitemap/), that comes with an `exclude` rule.